# Remove or hide Android AnimationDrawable when animation ends

Tags: android, animation

I'm creating a trivia game which plays a simple two frame animation before the answer is revealed. The animation fills the screen so that the answer isn't revealed until the animation is done. Everything works except that I can't get the animation to go away and reveal the answer. What I'm trying to do is call the Relative Layout that the animation ImageView is in and then do `ImageView_layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);`. I'm not getting any errors, but the relative layout ain't going away. Here's what I've got:

```
        Animation CorrAniShow = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.anim_fadein);
    Animation CorrAniHide = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.anim_fadeout);
    final RelativeLayout corrA_layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.aniC_Layout);
    final ImageView corrView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.corAn1);
    corrView.setBackgroundResource(R.anim.corr_anim);
    corrView.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            AnimationDrawable corAn = (AnimationDrawable)corrView.getBackground();
            corAn.start();
        }
    });     
    CorrAniHide.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
        public void onAnimationStart(final Animation arg0) {}
        public void onAnimationRepeat(final Animation arg0) {}
        public void onAnimationEnd(final Animation rg0){
            corrA_layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }
    });
```

Can anyone see why the view isn't gone? Is there a better way to make the animation go away? Thanks!

Comment: did you try to put test output in the AnimationListener to see, whether its methods are called? Where is CorrAniHide animation start?

Comment: You set me on the correct path, Berťák - thank you. You were right, the AnimationListener wasn't being called correctly. So I looked for AnimationListener coding and from there I figured it out.